# Am I doing something wrong in my ECS architecture if I must choose between coupling or copying code?

Tags: architecture, design-patterns, entity-component-system

I'm developing a somewhat simple, small roguelike game as my university project. Early into development I heard about Enity-Component-System and decided to go with that as my game's architecture. Since this is my first ever project using that design, I ran into some problems that I'm not sure are a result of the principles or my own mistakes. As an example:

I have an inventory system, handling inventory operations of managing, using and dropping items. The problem I ran into is the fact, that in order to actually do something like using potions, I have to either include an instance of the Health System (which I now realize is technically just a bunch of glorified functions dealing with health) or copy all that code into the inventory system, which I don't find a good solution either.

How do I get over this? I don't know if my design is simply flawed, or if I'm trying to be too much of a purist. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the Health System is just "a bunch of glorified functions", can you just make it a static class that can be accessed from any other class? What language are you using?

Comment: You could potentially have a "consumer" system that acts against an inventory/item component and the consuming entity's health stats component.

Comment: @Kevin I'm using C++, tbh I think that I might indeed do that, considering I've ran into this issue before with the AI system, which I resolved by just making the ai system have a reference to the health and positon system but I felt it wasn't a good solution

Comment: I don't think "Inventory" should be a system in the ECS sense. Systems should correspond to data transformations, but there's no one particular signature for data transformations that all inventory items need - a healing potion doesn't modify data the same way a scroll of fireball does. One-off item usage might be a good use case for a message queue, issuing a "heal" message for your health system to incorporate on its update pass.

Comment: @DMGregory After reading what you said, I realised my approach might not have been very good then. In what I'm building, I don't have any message systems in place and instead I rely on iterating through each entity and doing something for it depending on the AI/Player's action, with no update queue or anything like that. Sounds like a good idea, though, I'll probably utilize it next time I'll be building something, or maybe I'll refactor once I'm certain I have enough time left for that

Comment: When you say you're iterating over entities, not over lists of the same component set like an archetype, it sounds to me like you might be using a component-based architecture more akin to classic Unity, rather than a strict ECS. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think you're correct, I guess my understanding of what ECS stands for wasn't correct. Unlike unity, my components are purely data-based (there's no functionality attached to them on their own), it's simply that the entities own their components. Tbh I thought that as long as I decouple functionality from data in this way I could call it ECS, but I suppose that instead what ecs would be would be for each system to hold an entity id and a component corresponding to that id? I feel that it would make some things (that don't require their own systems) much harder to do though, like names etc.